# Passing Parameter to URL from code behind

Tags: asp.net, paypal

```
returnURL += "&return=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SuccessURL").ToString()
```

How do I pass a parameter to this url in ASP.NET, please?

I try like that but didn't work.  Neither did this:

```
returnURL += String.Format("return={0}&user{1}",Server.UrlEncode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SuccessURL").ToString()),65)
```

Code in web config:

```
<add key="SuccessURL" value="http://localhost:58690/Seller/Part1/Main.aspx" />
```

Comment: What do you mean that it doesn't work?  Do you get an error message?  Or does the extra text just not show in the URL?  Also, where is this code being called (in what event)?

Comment: the code should give me a url in paypal to return back to my website with this bidid but it don't give the return url but if i try like that returnURL += "&return=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SuccessURL").ToString() but me i need to pass the bid id

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you should be doing:

In the web.config:

```
<add key="SuccessURL" value="http://localhost:58690/Seller/Part1/Main.aspx?bidid={0}" />
```

And in the code:

```
var successUrl = String.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SuccessURL").ToString(), 65);

returnURL += "&return=" + successUrl;
```